# How much RAM does the 6th generation iPod touch have?

Tags: ipod-touch, memory

I would expect to have the same as the iPhone 6 - 1GB since it also has an A8. How much does it have?

Comment: You're going to have to wait for someone like iFixit to get one of these and do a tear-down before this question can be answered.

Comment: Apple did not put that information there in the "Tech Specs" page. It is either Apple thinks RAM is not really an important component or they want to hide the fact that they pennypinch on RAM.

Comment: @SinJeong-hun less RAM on a battery constrained device isn't always a bad thing. If you can get by with less, you have less to address and less to keep powered on.

Comment: I had owned iPod Touch 2th and 4th. The RAM shortage was a big problem, especially after upgrading the OS. Most Apple users would like to have more RAM even if it consumes slightly more power (most power is consumed by the display).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6th generation iPod touch has 1GB of RAM and runs at 1.10GHz according to [Matthew Panzarino](https://twitter.com/panzer/status/621389015325913088).

Comment: Well, that didn't take long. :) With those specs, this iPod might actually make a decent smartphone alternative...